# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face' OpenCV 4.7.0

Tags: python, opencv

After referring to some Stack Overflow answers I did pip install `opencv-contrib-python`, still I am getting those errors.

I am using OpenCV 4.7.0.

This is for a facial recognition project tutorial that I am following.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')
        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)
    return faceSamples,ids
print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') 
# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
File "/Users/sashuponnaganti/workspace/Facial Recognition Project/face_trainer.py", line 7, in <module>
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I already tried doing pip install `opencv-contrib-python` and I had already installed it so it made no difference.

Comment: Is the interpreter you installed `opencv-contrib-python` to the same as the one your running your project with?

Comment: Hey I just did : pip install opencv-python
and then : pip install opencv-contrib-python and it works. Maybe check again the environment so if you have a conda environment just write conda list to make sure that you have both installed in the environment

Comment: I tried everything you all said but none of them fixed the issue.

Comment: @Brian how do i check

Comment: @SashuPonnaganti How are you running your code?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been solved. I had installed all my opencv packages in a conda environment but was running it with the wrong interpreter.